# ffmpeg command doesn't work like it's supposed to

Tags: ffmpeg, video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='1-between(t,20,25)-between(t,40,70)', setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af "aselect='1-between(t,20,25)-between(t,40,70)', asetpts=N/SR/TB" output.mp4
```

What I am trying to do with this command is to remove 2 parts from a video the first part is from 20sec-25sec and the second part is from 40sec-70sec (The video is 3,15 minutes long). The problem is that many times there is a delay before the cut starts and it's a random one at that, I tried with a 1 minute video and changed some values and it worked, I also tried it with some longer videos the delay was bigger (one of the delays was 15 seconds). I can't seem to find out why this happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The setpts filter expressions will only work well if the remaining video is constant frame rate and the audio has no gaps in it.

Comment: Well the thing is the frame rate doesn't change, but what do you mean by saying "audio gaps", like the audio just stopping or something? Here is the video which I tried it on (the 3,15 minute one) [youtube link](https://youtu.be/iHdviZkM7S4) Also the longer videos which I also tried it on are interviews